# Zend_Pdf : Display Hello world on multiple pages in a Pdf document

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-pdf

How to display "hello world" on multiple pages in a single PDF document using Zend_Pdf?

```
 $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 
 $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
$page->setFont($font, 24) ->drawText('Hello World,', 72, 720);
 $pdf->pages[] = $page;
 $pdf->save('new.pdf');
```

I have tried the above code but is not able write chunk of code for iterating multiple pages

Comment: // create PDF
  $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
  
  // create A4 page
  $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
  
  // define font resource
  $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
  
  // set font for page
  // write text to page
  $page->setFont($font, 24)
       ->drawText('Hello World,', 72, 720);                         $pdf->pages[] = $page;                                               $pdf->save('new.pdf');

Comment: I have tried the above code. Can you please tell me How to display "hello world" on multiple pages in a single PDF document using Zend_Pdf

Comment: @Nida please edit that code into your question, then you'll be able to format it to make it easy to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the comment I just made, I am posting as an answer because code doesn't render well in comments.  If you want multiple pages with the same text, I guess you could simply do a loop:

```
<?php
    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 
    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);

    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
        $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $page->setFont($font, 24) ->drawText('Hello World page '.$i, 72, 720);
        $pdf->pages[] = $page;
    }

    $pdf->save('new.pdf');
?>
```

I haven't tested the code because, like h2ooooooo, I don't really use Zend_Pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest and say that I have no idea how `Zend_Pdf` works, but I can imagine something like this would work:

```
<?php
    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 
    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);

    $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $page->setFont($font, 24) ->drawText('Hello World page one,', 72, 720);
    $pdf->pages[] = $page;

    $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $page->setFont($font, 24) ->drawText('Hello World page two,', 72, 720);
    $pdf->pages[] = $page;

    $pdf->save('new.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: Yes, It works fine but I want some chunk of code which will dynamically iterate multiple pages and writes "hello world" on each page.

Comment: @Nida not sure what you want to achieve but if the above code works, I guess you could simply do a for... loop to achieve what you want.